# Auto sudoers entry on ssh login by a non-sudo user

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, sudo

I am facing this problem in Gcloud VM (ubuntu 14.04 image).

As an admin user, I create another user, say ***UserNew***, without giving `sudo` privilege to him, using this command:

```
sudo adduser UserNew
```

I carefully checked entries in `/etc/sudoers`. This user is not present over there.

But as soon as someone does `ssh` with ***UserNew*** account, its entry gets created in `/etc/sudoers` and it can run `sudo` commands afterwards.

I did open an issue with them, but am I doing something wrong which is letting this happen?

Comment: must be something in PAM...never seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/):

> "All Linux user accounts in your project are granted root access to
>   your instances. By default, new Linux user accounts are added to the
>   following user groups upon account creation:
>
> - `gce-sudoers` - Gives root access
> - `gce-users` - General users group
>
> The `gce-sudoers` group is automatically maintained by the Cloud User
>   Accounts service and contains every Linux user account in your
>   project. If you wanted to restrict root access to certain accounts,
>   remove the default policy at:
>
> `/etc/sudoers.d/gcua`
>
> Next, create your own group and add a configuration similar to the
>   `gcua` file in the `sudoers.d` folder."